# RabbitMQ configuration file in windows: tcp_listeners not working

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

I am rather new in RabbitMQ.

I am trying to change the interface for rabbitMQ, and in my rabbitMQ connfig i have the following :

```
[
  {rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners, [{"192.168.1.100",5678}]}
  ]}
].
```

The error I get is :

```
exception exit: {listen_error,{acceptor,{192,168,1,100},5678},
                                  eaddrnotavail}
```

If i add 127.0.0.1 instead of this ip, there is no error.

Am i missing some kind of set up here?

Answer (score 0):

Rabbit can't use the provided `IP + port` combination. Likely `192.168.1.100` is not the IP of the machine, or the port `5678` is already in use.

Comment: Great answer. The original poster should verify this, follow up here, and mark this as the accepted answer.